# Facebook iOS SDK - what is the right way to set up the controller

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I tried to integrate Facebook in my iOS app, using the new Facebook iOS SDK. I managed to authorize the app I created on Facebook, but after the iOS app reloads (after logging in), delegates like `-(void)fbdidload` don't get called.

The controller I am using is presented modally at some point in my app. Could this be the problem? Which is the right way to set up the controller? I am quite convince this is the problem, because this is the only difference between my app and the demo app they provided. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your class is a FBSessionDelegate, and when you authorize your app make sure you set yourself as the delegate.

These are the callbacks after logging in:

```
/**
 * Called after user has logged in.
 */   
- (void)fbDidLogin{
}

/**
 * Called when the user dismissed the dialog without logging in.
 */
- (void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled{
}
```

If it is not switching back to your app follow the instructions to add your app id to the info.plst

> The last thing that needs to be
>   accomplished to enable SSO support is
>   a change to the .plist file that
>   handles configuration for the app.
>   XCode creates this file automatically
>   when the project is created. A
>   specific URL needs to be registered in
>   this file that uniquely identifies the
>   app with iOS. Create a new row named
>   URL types with a single item, URL
>   Schemes, containing a single value,
>   fbYOUR_APP_ID (the literal characters
>   fb followed by your app id).

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/